# Is there an EKS policy for restricting redundancy for GPU servers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

Is there an EKS policy for restricting redundancy for GPU servers?  If so, where can we edit that policy in the EKS dashboard?

The issue:  we deploy Riva Speech Skills container, which runs on a GPU server.  However, if we deploy a 2nd variant of the Riva Speech Skills container, then the deployment fails due to gpu-count-restriction in our k8s cluster.

Error log in CloudWatch for our EKS instance:

```
"Unable to schedule pod; no fit; waiting" pod="riva/riva-api-xxxxx" err="0/14 nodes are available: 1 Insufficient nvidia.com/gpu, ...
```